# Webserver inaccessible when client accessing using a VPN (such as NordVPN)

Tags: webserver, virtualhost

I have a webserver I'm playing with on a Linux box running Apache2. It's sitting behind a pfSense firewall who's NAT'ing port 80 & 433 to the webserver with the below rules. I can access the webserver from my phone or other mobile devices which are not on the local network just fine. The problem occurs when I enable NordVPN on my phone or a laptop and all of a sudden I get error `The request has timed out. [NSURL.ErrorDomain]`. I can see a connection attempt in the logs which I have pasted below.

The domain is registered with Route53 on AWS with an alias from `foo.com` to `www.foo.com`, then an A record to my IP from `www.foo.com`. There are no health checks and all are simple records.

Firewall Rules:

```
Interface   Protocol    Source Address  Source Ports    Dest. Address   Dest. Ports NAT IP  NAT Ports   Description Actions
WAN TCP *   *   WAN address 443 (HTTPS) 192.168.3.9 443 (HTTPS) webserver HTTPS   
WAN TCP *   *   WAN address 80 (HTTP)   192.168.3.9 80 (HTTP)   webserver HTTP
```

Apache Log when page stops working:

`103.137.14.220 - - [08/Jun/2021:12:45:35 +0000] "-" 408 -`

`103.137.14.220 - - [08/Jun/2021:12:45:35 +0000] "-" 408 -`

When not using the VPN the log looks fine with the normal requests and the page loads normally.

I have no idea why using a VPN service would stop someone accessing the page.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs it looks like the connection is made to the web server, but then the client does not respond after that. Maybe you need to look at the ephemeral port settings on your firewall. Maybe the VPN requires a higher port range on subsequent connections.

Comment: I checked my firewall, it doesn't limit the port range unless you specify.